# Cannot get file send from react native to .net core api - upload image

Tags: c#, reactjs, react-native, .net-core

I have problem with the upload file in React Native.

I have an API to upload image base on .net core

.net core API

```
public async Task<RestResult<ImageUploadResponse>> UploadImage(IFormFile file, [FromQuery] string targetSize = TargetSize.KeepSameSize)
    {
        var respone = new ImageUploadResponse();
        try
        {
            if (file is null)
            {
                return new RestResult<ImageUploadResponse>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, MessageCode.UPLOAD_INVALID_IMAGE, new MessageData().FindMessage(MessageCode.UPLOAD_INVALID_IMAGE));
            }
            if (file is object && file.Length > _imageConfig.Value.MaximumImageLength)
            {
                return new RestResult<ImageUploadResponse>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, MessageCode.UPLOAD_INVALID_SIZE, new MessageData().FindMessage(MessageCode.UPLOAD_INVALID_SIZE));
            }
        }
    }
```

And I have the React Native code to upload image file

axios call API

```
componentDidMount() {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", {
      uri: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILTQq.png",
      type: "image/png",
      name: "ILTQq.png"
    });

    axios
      .post("https://localhost:44306/api/tab/v1.0/upload-image", data, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
      })
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data.results;
        this.setState({ data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

But when I run, I cannot get the file upload in the backend. Help me, please!

Comment: have you try to send data from another client? like a command line client maybe curl...With that you can first check the server

Comment: you are sending json data not the actual file `byte` array you have to use the Reader in Javascript to read the file and send the `bytes` check example at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#example

Comment: and if you want to pass the absolute url of the file, may be pass as json as you have done, and save the file URI at server, but if you want to save that file to your server/DB may be get the bytes at server as you are sending the absolute URI of the image file.

Comment: Yes, I have already tested the server with the postman to make request, but when I try to test with codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ajax-request-using-react-and-axios-forked-lqfe5?file=/src/index.js to make request from axios, I cannot get the file from IFromFile of server, so maybe the file that I append is a problem?

Comment: man your local code and code on sandbox is different.  sandbox code is correct as you need file from input[type="file], and from codesandbox are you hitting correct endpoint? in url, instead of `API`, you are using `AP1`. I'm expecting its not mistake.

Comment: I just make the sample in code sandbox to test API, In the real application, I am using React Native, so It doesn't have the  input[type="file], and I have to use the object: example: {
      uri: ""file:///data/user/0/com.qlchungcu/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/image.png",
      type: "image/png",
      name: "image.png"
    }) , so could I'm using this object to send a file from React Native App?  and the .net core API will use what to get a File that send from App(Currently I'm using IFromFile, and It doesn't work) @DeepakSharma